# Report Builder 3.0 Filter for current month in Tablix

Tags: date, filter, reportbuilder3.0

I would like to filter in the tablix in Report Builder 3.0 to include only data from the current month. I have successfully filtered for only yesterday using the expression
=dateadd("d",-1,today())
but I cannot find an expression which works correctly to include all data for month to date.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like the following:
You would have a End Date as `GETDATE()`
and Start Date as

```
= DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE())
```